# Expression that denotes impossibility in a succeeding clause

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I’m looking for an idiom or phrase that describes the impossibility/ludicrousness of something by comparing it to the near or full impossibility/ludicrousness of its lesser degree in a succeeding clause. It should denote a flustered/sarcastic disposition. I’m fairly sure it consists of two words.

(Someone asks you if you can walk 10 miles)

> “I can barely walk 1 mile, _ 10!”

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Less colloquial version of "(X), never mind (Y)"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79286/less-colloquial-version-of-x-never-mind-y) (never mind, let alone, and even less,  still less...)

Comment: Provide one answer is laborious, "10 don't even think about it !"

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for  `let alone`

From [Merriam Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20alone)

> **let alone :** conjunction    : to say nothing of : not to mention —used especially to emphasize the improbability  of a contrasting
> example
>
> he would never walk again let alone play golf— Sports Illus.
>
> how many ever see an Ambassador or Minister, let   alone a President—
> Robert Lacville

Answer (score 2):

Looks a bit weird in your sentence, but:

> I can barely walk 1 mile, **much** **less** 10!

From [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=much%20less%20define&oq=much%20less%20define&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i15i22i30l3j0i22i30l7j0i15i22i30j0i10i15i22i30j0i15i22i30l2.4181j0j7&client=ms-android-fi&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8):

> used to introduce something as being even less likely or suitable than something else already mentioned.
> "*what woman would consider a date with him, much less a marriage?"*